# next js compile but page not loading in browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, firefox, next.js

I have recently started with Next.js and React to create UI web pages. It has worked well till for some reason Next.js start to show the message:

```
⨯ src/app/page.tsx (10:4) @ get_width
⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

where:

```
const get_width = ():number => {
    return window.innerWidth;
}
```

The problem is supposed to be solved using `useState`, so I change it(the code that I found is not exactly this):

```
const get_width = ():number => {
    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState((window !== undefined) ? window.innerWidth : 0);
    return windowSize; 
}
```

and another error comes:

```
⨯ src/app/page.tsx (18:25) @ self
⨯ ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

Due to the use of `self.crypto.randomUUID()`. The solution I have found is to import `import crypto from 'crypto';` and use `crypto.randomUUID()` instead. Here something strange happens: Next says that there is no error in compilation but the page keeps loading. Only when I return to the previous code it throws an error, otherwise the loading never ends.
I tried to change the port, the version of Node and Next, using crypto without import it, but neither repairs the problem. I have made another server and the page opens correctly, so is there anything that I have made wrong?